# How to use JsonB in feature Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, jsonb, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

Please, I need help.

I start working with cucumber tests and I need to test a fonctionality that uses a jsonB data as input.

this is my feature

Given ....

When....

|id| name  | message    |

|5 | "test | jsonb data |

the question is how to pass my jsonB data in the feature ?

example of message:

{"class": "testclass",
"email": "x.y@email",
"author": ""
}

I found in google that I need to use Pojo.

I generated my pojo class from my json but i dont know how to use this pojo class in the feature ?

Any help please ?

Comment: First you need to handle your DataTable in your step definition. Here is how: https://www.baeldung.com/cucumber-data-tables

Answer (score 0):

> I generated my pojo class from my json but i dont know how to use this
> pojo class in the feature ?

Once you have generated the pojo class ,  you can utilize that in feature and step def like below.  Example is for this sample pojo .

```
public class addUserPojo {
    
    private String FirstName;
   private  String LastName;

  
    public addUserPojo(String fname, String lname ){
        this.FirstName = fname;
         this.LastName=lname;
        
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
         return LastName;
    }
   
    }
}
```

Gherkin scenario is

```
Scenario: Add a user using pojo class in a scenario using data table and @DataTableType
      Given I open the site "http://www.www.com"
       When I add  user with passing info to pojo class
        |FirstName|LastName|
        |TestFirstName3 |TestLastName3 |
```

And in step definition

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import io.cucumber.java.DataTableType;
    import com.test.support.addUserPojo;

 public class StepDef  {   

        @DataTableType
                public addUserPojo userentry(Map<String, String> entry) {
                return new addUserPojo(entry.get("FirstName"),entry.get("LastName"));
                } 
    
    
        @When("I add  user with passing info to pojo class")
                public void AddUserWithPOJO( List<addUserPojo> adduser) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
                   
                     for (addUserPojo addUserFields : adduser) {
        
                         System.out.println("firstname..."+addUserFields.getFirstName());
                         System.out.println("LastName..."+addUserFields.getLastName());
                                  
                         
                     }
                     
               } 
}
```

More information on [@Datatabletype and other types](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/configuration/)